# type variable T with upper bounds LineChart,View

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have the following class:

```
public class LineChart extends AppCompatActivity{
private LineChart mChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_line_chart);

    mChart = findViewById(R.id.linechart);
  }
}
```

And an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linechart">

</com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>
```

My problem now is that when i try to get the Line Chart with `findViewById(R.id.linechart)` i get the error:

> Error:(42, 24) error: incompatible types: no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds LineChart,View
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends View declared in method findViewById(int)

If you look in the [MPAndroidChart Wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Getting-Started) you will see that i did nothing wrong (i hope). Can someone tell me please where my mistake is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give your `Activity` a different name.

You have a conflict with the name `LineChart` so when you do the `findViewById(...)` lookup it thinks you want to use your `LineChart` instead of the one from the library you are using.

This is what is causing the incompatible types message since your `LineChart` does not extend `View`.